# How do I create a PDF template and how can I fill that template with values in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, templates, pdf

We have a Node.js application. We want to pull PDF files from an AWS S3 bucket, fill some content into them, and then send them as email attachments. The problem is two-fold:

1. How do we create PDFs with placeholders that can be filled with values dynamically.
2. How to fill those placeholders in Node.js after pulling them from AWS S3.

What I mean by 1) is that we want to create templates. For example, a PDF template might container the follow:

```
Hello {name}, we would like to invite you to {address} for our Christmas party on {date}.
```

We then want to upload this to S3 and when we need to send it from our Node.js, we pull it from S3, fill {name}, {address}, and {date} with actual values, and then send it as an email attachment.

How can we create 1) and then how can we do 2)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% your request but you can do it in two step:

1. Write your template in Word and customize the dynamic parts with [docx-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx-templates)
2. Take your customized Word and convert it to PDF with libreoffice using [libreoffice-convert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libreoffice-convert)

You should find good starting examples on their supporting sites.